# Executing a method from a parent class in a child class

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I am trying to create a new attribute for the child class `SubClass` by using a method in the parent class `MyClass`. This method – `method_of_class` – should take an array from the child class `SubClass` as an argument and return a value `result`.

The following is just some dummy code to clearly illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
import numpy as np


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,var1,var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        
        self.class_array = np.array([[self.var1, self.var2],
                                     [-self.var2, self.var1]])
        
    def method_of_class(self,some_array):

        intermediate_array = np.matmul(some_array, self.class_array)
        result = np.matmul(self.class_array.transpose(), intermediate_array)

        return result
        
        
class SubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self,var1,var2,var3,var4):
        super().__init__(var1,var2)
        super().method_of_class(some_array)
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
        
        self.subclass_array = np.array([[self.var3, self.var4],
                                        [self.var4, self.var3]])
        
        self.new_array = method_of_class(self.subclass_array)

d = SubClass(1,1,1,1)
print(d.new_array)
```

The code does not work, and I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-8b58ebadf6be> in <module>
----> 1 d = SubClass(1,1,1,1)
      2 
      3 print(d.new_array)

<ipython-input-67-66bf10d774f2> in __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4)
     19     def __init__(self,var1,var2,var3,var4):
     20         super().__init__(var1,var2)
---> 21         super().method_of_class(some_array)
     22         self.var3 = var3
     23         self.var4 = var4

NameError: name 'some_array' is not defined
```

Comment: This is about the simplest possible task that can be attempted with inheritance (i.e., that specifically involves using inheritance to solve the problem). What happened when you tried putting `python inheritance tutorial` into a search engine, and looked at example code?

Comment: Or, a more guided explanation: How would you write the code if `method_of_class` had been defined in the `SubClass` directly? Now, why do you think it's called "inheritance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inherit from a class, its methods become available to instances of the child class, so there is no need to write `super().method_of_class(some_array)`. Especially because you did not define the variable `some_array` when doing so.

Instead, simply state that you want to use `method_of_class` from this instance when creating `self.new_array`:

```py
class SubClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self,var1,var2,var3,var4):
        super().__init__(var1,var2)
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
        
        self.subclass_array = np.array([[self.var3, self.var4],
                                        [self.var4, self.var3]])
        
        self.new_array = self.method_of_class(self.subclass_array)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The "self" is my weak point – I frequently forget it. Also, thank you for mentioning that I do not need the super().method_of_class. I doubted that I needed it, but put it in to try and fix the code. Could you please give an example of when one should use the super().some_method(arg) ?

Comment: @euler132 you are welcome! Glad I could help. You might need to explicitly call `super().some_method` if your child class also defined a method called `some_method`. In this case `self.some_method` will use the `some_method` from the child class, but you can get the definition from the parent class by calling `super().some_method`. Hope that helped!

Comment: Cool! I know OOP can be tricky to begin with (and there are aspects about it that remain tricky as you go). But OOP is not just tremendously useful, it is also simply a cool concept to wrap your head around!